# SQL different jointure and WHERE clause can be wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Here are my tables :

**auth_keys** :

```
id    /    keys    / user 
1     /    12345   /   1
```

**products ** :

```
id    / company    /   name
1     /  1         /   iphone
2     /  2         /   iphone
```

**companies** :

```
id    / name       /   mkey
1     / myComp     /   54321
```

And here is my sql request :

```
SELECT 
    products.id_product AS id_product, 
    auth_keys.keys AS vkey,
    auth_keys.user AS user_id
FROM 
    auth_keys
JOIN 
    products
LEFT JOIN 
    companies ON products.company = companies.id
WHERE 
    products.name_product = "iphone"
    AND companies.mkey = "54321" 
HAVING 
    vkey = "none"
```

I want to things :

- the `id_products` which I get by getting first the `id_company` THEN the `name_product` because I could have the same name product for two different companies. This part is OK.
- I want the `user_key` value `WHERE keys = "12345" OR "NONE"` and that's my problem. Everything work if keys = "12345" but I don't get anything if keys= "none/nothing"...

I'd like to get the first result, id_product, even if I can't match the `user_key`...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: ***WHAT database system*** and which version? SQL is just the query language - used by **many** database products. It would be helpful to know what you're really using - MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? DB2? Something else??

Comment: it's in mysql, latest version :)

Comment: `LEFT JOIN  companies ... WHERE companies.mkey = "54321"` turns it back to an `INNER JOIN`. Probably you want `companies.mkey = "54321"` in the `ON` clause not the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SELECT 
    products.id_product AS id_product, 
    auth_keys.keys AS vkey,
    auth_keys.user AS user_id
    FROM auth_keys
    JOIN products
    LEFT JOIN companies ON products.company = companies.id
    WHERE 
    products.name_product = "iphone"
    AND (companies.mkey = "54321"or vkey = "none")
```

No need for the "having" as that is used with the "group by" clause to filter the aggregated results.

Comment: in that way, i get all the auth_keys rows...If i group by id_product, i get a random key so it could do the trick cause if i test the random key, i'll see that it doesn't match with "none"

Comment: Nop not working because i get also a random user_id value, even with a exissting key...

Answer (score 0):

I am really struggling to understand how the tables join together. You appear to want a join onto auth_keys without any condition beyond that the key must either be 12345 or NONE. Not sure what you want if there is a match on both though.

However quick try

```
SELECT products.id_product AS id_product, 
    auth_keys.keys AS vkey,
    auth_keys.user AS user_id
FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN companies
ON products.company = companies.id
AND companies.mkey = "54321"
LEFT OUTER JOIN auth_keys
ON auth_keys.keys IN ('12345', 'NONE')
WHERE products.name_product = "iphone"
```